# How to concatenate two arrays in Go

Tags: arrays, go, slice

A basic question that I'm struggling to find an answer for as there are a lot of answers about how to join two *slices* using the append function and the spread operator which erroneously use the word 'array'.

I am new to Go and have made the assumption that using sized arrays is good practice where the size is known. However I am struggling to work with arrays as I can't figure out how to do simple operations such as concatenation. Here is some code.

```
var seven [7]int

five := [5]int{1,2,3,4,5}
two := [2]int{6,7}

//this doesn't work as both the inputs and assignment are the wrong type
seven = append(five,two)

//this doesn't work as the assignment is still the wrong type
seven = append(five[:],two[:])

//this works but I'm not using arrays anymore so may as well use slices everywhere and forget sizing
seven2 := append(five[:],two[:])
```

As far as I can see I can either just give up on arrays and use slices exclusively or I could write a loop to explicitly construct the new array. Is there a third option?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`append()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) can only be used to append elements to a slice. If you have an array, you can't pass that directly to `append()`.

What you may do is [slice](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) the array, so you get a slice (which will use the array as its backing store), and you can use that slice as the target and source of elements.

For example:

```
s := seven[:0]
s = append(s, five[:]...)
s = append(s, two[:]...)
fmt.Println(seven)
```

This will print (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/qzhHhu3mGRx)):

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
```

Also note that since `append()` returns the resulting slice, it's possible to write all this in one line:

```
_ = append(append(seven[:0], five[:]...), two[:]...)
```

(Storing the result is not needed here because we have and want to use only the backing array, but in general that is not the case.)

This outputs the same, try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/sdtessyaHvb). Although this isn't very readable, so it's not worth compacting it into a single line.

Although when you have the target array, "appending" arrays is nothing more than copying them to the target, to the proper position. For that, you may use the builtin [`copy()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy) function too. Note that the `copy()` function also accepts only slices, so you have to slice the arrays here too.

```
copy(seven[:], five[:])
copy(seven[len(five):], two[:])
fmt.Println(seven)
```

This will output the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JfOw7w4_va2).

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't properly understood how the backing array is modified in place even though the returned value is a slice.

Comment: @SimonN If the `append()` can be performed "in-place", no new array is allocated, the existing backing array is used.

Comment: @SimonN, please read [this](https://blog.golang.org/slices). [This](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals) is also a must read.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `copy`

```
copy(seven[:], five[:])
copy(seven[5:], two[:])
fmt.Printf("%v\n", seven)
> [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate two arrays in go using copy function

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
 five := [5]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
 two := [2]int{6, 7}

 var n [len(five) + len(two)]int
 copy(n[:], five[:])
 copy(n[len(five):], two[:])
 fmt.Println(n)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

Golang runtime used to check whether current index exceeds the maximum possible.
On the side of array, it look ups its type (which contain its len and reference to the element type), because that's type, that can be registered only at compile time.

```golang
// each array mention with unique size creates new type
array := [5]byte{1,2,3,4,5}
```

On the side of slice, it look ups their header which looks like:

```golang
type slice {
      data *byte
      len int
      cap int // capacity, the maximum possible index
}
```

As you can see, any slice is a single structure with data and len, cap fields, meanwhile array is just single pointer to data (`*byte`).

When you trying to convert array to slice, it just creates slice  header and fills fields with:

```
slice := array[:]

==

slice := Slice{}
slice.data = array
slice.len = type_of(array).len
slice.cap = type_of(array).len
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that simply by converting array into slice:

```
arr1 := [...]int {1,2,3,}
arr2 := [...]int {4,5,6, }

//arr3 = arr1 + arr2                // not allowed

// converting arrays into slice 
slc_arr1, slc_arr2 := arr1[:], arr2[:]
slc_arr3 := make([]int, 0)

slc_arr3 = append(slc_arr1, slc_arr2...)
fmt.Println(slc_arr3)               // [1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a more general way of appending an array of any type(once Golang has generics, but for now this solution is specific to strings. Just change the type as appropriate). The notion of Fold comes from Functional Programming.  Note I have also included a filter function which also uses Fold. The solution is not stack safe but in many cases that does not matter. It can be made stack safe with trampolining.  At the end is an example of its usage.

```golang
func FoldRightStrings(as, z []string, f func(string, []string) []string) []string {
    if len(as) > 1 { //Slice has a head and a tail.
        h, t := as[0], as[1:len(as)]
        return f(h, FoldRightStrings(t, z, f))
     } else if len(as) == 1 { //Slice has a head and an empty tail.
        h := as[0]
        return f(h, FoldRightStrings([]string{}, z, f))
    }
    return z
}

func FilterStrings(as []string, p func(string) bool) []string {
    var g = func(h string, accum []string) []string {
        if p(h) {
            return append(accum, h)
        } else {
            return accum
        }
    }
    return FoldRightStrings(as, []string{}, g)
}

func AppendStrings(as1, as2 []string) []string {
    var g = func(h string, accum []string) []string {
        return append(accum, h)
    }
    return FoldRightStrings(as1, as2, g)
}

func TestAppendStringArrays(t *testing.T) {
    strings := []string{"a","b","c"}
    bigarray := AppendStrings(AppendStrings(strings, strings),AppendStrings(strings, strings))

    if diff := deep.Equal(bigarray, []string{"a","b","c","c","b","a","a","b","c","c","b","a"}); diff != nil {
        t.Error(diff)
    }
}
```